# How to call `flatMap` multiple times? - the FP-ish way

Tags: scala, functional-programming, flatmap

### Question

When playing with a toy example - *positions, a knight can reach on a chessboards after doing `n` moves, starting at a certain position `x`* - I wonder if there exists a cleaner solution (in the sense of conciseness and functional programming)

- to execute `flatMap` (neglect the `filter` for now) a certain number of times (once for each move)
- to have an (even) more FP-ish way of coding

### What I tried

- a simple recursive variant **`move(...)`**
- a variant that uses function composition **`move2(...)`**

### Code

```
object ChessFun {

  import scala.annotation.tailrec

  case class Position(x: Int, y: Int)

  case class Chessboard(widthX: Int, widthY: Int) {
    def positionOnBoard(pos: Position) = {
      (0 <= pos.x) && (pos.x < widthX) && (0 <= pos.y) && (pos.y < widthY)
    }
  }

  def knightMoves(pos: Position) = Set(
    Position(pos.x + 1, pos.y + 2),
    Position(pos.x + 2, pos.y + 1),
    Position(pos.x + 1, pos.y - 2),
    Position(pos.x + 2, pos.y - 1),
    Position(pos.x - 1, pos.y + 2),
    Position(pos.x - 2, pos.y + 1),
    Position(pos.x - 1, pos.y - 2),
    Position(pos.x - 2, pos.y - 1)
  )

  def move(startPos: Position, steps: Int, chessboard: Chessboard) : Set[Position] = {
    @tailrec
    def moveRec(accum: Set[Position], remainingSteps: Int) : Set[Position] = {
      remainingSteps match {
        case 0 ⇒ accum
        // otherwise  
        case _ ⇒ {
          // take a position and calculate next possible positions
          val a: Set[Position] = accum
            .flatMap( pos ⇒ knightMoves(pos)
            .filter( newPos ⇒ chessboard.positionOnBoard(newPos)) )
          moveRec(a, remainingSteps - 1)
        }
      }
    }

    moveRec(Set(startPos), steps)
  }

  def move2(startPos: Position, steps: Int, chessboard: Chessboard) : Set[Position] = {
    val nextFnc : Set[Position] => Set[Position] = {
      positions => positions
        .flatMap( pos ⇒ knightMoves(pos)
        .filter( newPos ⇒ chessboard.positionOnBoard(newPos)) )
    }

    // nexts composes nextFnc `steps` times
    val nexts = (0 until steps).map( i ⇒ nextFnc).reduce( _ compose _)

    // apply nexts
    nexts(Set(startPos))
  }  

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val startPos = Position(0,0)
    println( move( Position(0,0), 2, Chessboard(8, 8)) )
    println( move2( Position(0,0), 2, Chessboard(8, 8)) )
  }
}
```

## Edit - 2015-11-29 - 02:25AM

With some inspiration from the answer given by Alvaro Carrasco, I have rewritten method `move2` elegantly as:

```
def move2b(startPos: Position, steps: Int, chessboard: Chessboard) : Set[Position] = {
  val nextFnc : Set[Position] => Set[Position] = {
    _.flatMap( knightMoves(_).filter( chessboard.positionOnBoard(_)) )
  }

  List.fill(steps)(nextFnc).reduce(_ compose _)(Set(startPos))
}
```

#### Questions:

- Why should one use Scalaz and `Kleisli` as suggested by Alvaro?  (not meant as blaming, I want arguments ;) )
- Is an even more elegant solution possible?

Comment: Looks like a better fit for [codereview.SE] to me

Comment: Honestly, this is not meant as a code review. First, structure of methods is well defined. Second, the code is presented to have a full running example. The central question (as emphazised in the heading) is how to execute `flatMap` multiple times in the most concise and functional programming way. Thanks for your understanding!

Comment: I guess the idea of code review is not to make it working, but actually simplify and beautify code

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if it's any more FP, but here's a version that uses scalaz `>=>`.

```
import scalaz.Kleisli
import scalaz.syntax.kleisli._
import scalaz.std.list._

def move3 (startPos: Position, steps: Int, chessboard: Chessboard) : Set[Position] = {
  val validMove = Kleisli {a: Position => knightMoves(a).filter(chessboard.positionOnBoard).toList}
  List.fill(steps)(validMove).reduce(_ >=> _)(startPos).toSet
}
```

Had to use List, since there's no Bind instance for Set.

Update: Removed `step-1` which was a remnant from a previous version I was trying out.

Comment: `List.fill(steps-1)` seems to be incorrect. At least for Scala, it has to be `List.fill(step)`.

Comment: Second, could you elaborateon why one needs a `KleislI`? (see my edit with approach 2b) )

Comment: @MartinSenne Kleisli seems to me (not an expert) to be more appropriate and more concise when we know the value produced by the first Monad goes straight into the next one. With `flatMap`, that is not always the case, where it *could* be ignored or replace by something else.